# How to add css selector in firebug' style's area?

Tags: firebug

How to add new css class or id and then write properties for html element in firebug's right side css pane. like we can write in web developer toolbar > edit css

Comment: You can Add rule in style tab if you want to define new class or ID at same time.

Comment: Firebug's interface has changed. In the CSS Tab you right click in the white area to get option "New Rule..."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can right click on Style Tab then Edit Element Style... or New Property...

You can also enable/disable styles by clicking a RED Circle with diagonal line.
If the style becomes grayed it means that it is disabled.

Comment: we can only add or edit properties of already defined css class or ie . i want o know how to add new css class or id?

Comment: You just need to edit the css class or id on the HTML tab, just right click(Edit/Add Attribute) or double click on a particular tag.

Answer (score 5):

Dunno if I'm too late with this, but if you go to the CSS tab in Firebug, then Edit one of the CSS scripts, you can add the class selector and CSS anywhere, and your changes will show up immediately.

Comment: Brilliant stuff! Never knew of this :D

Answer (score 4):

Actually none of the answers were correct... 
**Edit element style** edits the **inline style** of the element.
**New propery** adds a new css property to **the actual css selector**, what you clicked on.
There is an Add rule menu, when you right click on the css part and there you can define a new selector and this was the original question.

Comment: I think you are right, I remember an Add Rule button, the thing is I can't find it anymore.